# Hiding fields in SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, list-form, content-editor-web-part, classic-experience

I have a SharePoint Online list, I want to be able to go to create a new item and hide certain fields from users.  How do I hide the GeoLocationField in the form only?

I was able to hide other fields using content editor using the input below, but unable to do so with this section.  I'm guessing it has to do with GeoLocationField being a different type.

```
(":input[title='Title']").closest("tr").hide();
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide this field from all forms(new/display/edit)? Assuming you are using classic experience, right?

Comment: Yup, classic experience.  That is fine, hiding it in all the forms. I didn’t see the option to hide columns after changing the management setting.

Comment: Are you not able to see the fields under content type columns or not able to see "Hidden" option for this particular field?

Comment: I see it now, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the column from all forms by following below steps:

1. Go to List settings --> Advanced settings.
2. Set **Allow management of content types?** to "Yes" and click "OK".

[image]

3. On List settings page, Click on content type name under "Content Types"
   section.

[image]

4. Click on column name under "Columns" section.

[image]

5. Set **Hidden (Will not appear in forms)** under "Column Settings"
6. Click OK

[image]